# Remove string from array multiple key name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form which, all of my form fields name start with a prepared "Family." for example:

```
Family.Name
Family.LastName
```

What I need to be converted:

```
Name 
LastName
```

Now I want to remove **"Family."** if exists, before sending to server using **serializeArray()** jquery function.
Here is my current code:

```
var formData = $('#FamilySpouseCreate').serializeArray();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'Post',
                    url: '/Profile/SpouseCreate',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function() {
                        window.location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        errorHandler(xhr);
                    }
                });
```

How can I modify **formData** to remove "Family." Prepend from array index name?

Comment: Try maybe something like this: 
var formData = $('#FamilySpouseCreate').serializeArray();

formData.map((item)=>{
 item.name = item.name.slice(item.name.indexOf('.')+1);
 return item;
})

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
var formData = $('#FamilySpouseCreate').serializeArray();
var dataObj = {};

$.each(formData, function(i, field){
  fieldName = field.name.replace('Family.', '');
  dataObj[fieldName] = field.value;
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: '/Profile/SpouseCreate',
    data: dataObj,
    success: function() {
        window.location.reload();
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        errorHandler(xhr);
    }
});
```

Fiddler [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Arif2009/7bx9o2qf/4/)

**OR**

If you just want to rename the field name. You can do it like this way:

```
var formData = $('#FamilySpouseCreate').serializeArray();
$.each(formData, function(i, field){
  field.name = field.name.replace('Family.', '');
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: '/Profile/SpouseCreate',
    data: formData,
    success: function() {
        window.location.reload();
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        errorHandler(xhr);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var formData = $('#FamilySpouseCreate').serializeArray();
$.each(formData, function(i, item) {
    item.name = item.name.replace("Family.", "");
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/s18nfeq6/1/